# How to install third-party APIs?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, intellij-idea, apache-commons

Sorry if this has been asked before, I searched but couldn't find anything.

I'm a novice (like, just now moving on to true object-oriented programming) Java programmer taking AP Computer Science online. Outside of class, I've been working on some programs for personal use. One program that I'd like to write needs some third-party APIs, notably Apache Commons. I'd also like to have Google's Guava API available, among others. The only problem is, I have no idea how to make the APIs available to my IDE. I'm still trying to decide on an IDE, so I'd like to make the APIs available system-wide if possible, but at minimum I need compatibility with IntelliJ IDEA 9 CE. I'm on Mac OSX, but I sometimes have to work on a Windows PC.

Comment: Some advice for you: regular use of IDEs like NetBeans severely cripples certain aspects of the learning process. In general there is just too much help spoon-fed to people whether it be from auto-complete features or syntax checking. I'd advise that even if you plan on using these IDEs regularly, you at least see how it is to really go out there and simply open up Textpad or some simple text editor, and then compile your projects through an Ant build process or the command-line. That way, you really get down to the core of what you're doing without the black-box magic of IDEs.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to install the APIs in NetBeans from your answer, but it disappeared. (For the curious, Tools > Libraries > New Library)  Also, for the class, I've been using BlueJ which is basically a glorified text editor with compiler, but if it will make me a better programmer, I'll certainly try building everything in a text editor.

Comment: it certainly will. Syntax highlight and auto-indent is fine, but integration with the compiler and the build process are definitely evil for a novice.

Comment: Re-posted the answer haha. And yes, I am ashamed to say that it took me by surprise to see what was actually happening when you press "Build" in NetBeans after naively using the IDE for a year or so. And to be honest, I have no intention of ever going back (though sometimes they're nice for large package organization, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the necessary JARs and then in NetBeans, I believe there is a "Libraries" or "Classpath" menu option somewhere toward the end. Thats where you'll need to add the libraries you plan on using by referencing any JARs you've downloaded.

[You can see it here from their website](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath)